# How to solve this using power series method $\left(x^2+2\right)y''\:+\:xy'\:-\:y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

$\left(x^2+2\right)y''\:+\:xy'\:-\:y=0$

What's next after this?

$\sum _{n=2}^{\infty }\:n\left(n-1\right)a_nx^n+2\:\sum _{n=0}^{\infty \:}\left(n+2\right)\left(n-1\right)a_{n+2}x^n+\sum _{n=2}^{\infty \:\:}na_n^{\:}x^n\:-\:\sum _{n=0}^{\infty \:}a_n^{\:}x^n = 0.$

Comment: How can i delete this picture without deleting the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restarting from scratch, we assume that the DE $$ (x^2+2)y''+xy'-y=0 \tag{1}$$
has an analytic solution in a neighbourhood of zero, given by
$$ y(x) = \sum_{n\geq 0} a_n x^n \tag{2} $$
In terms of the coefficients, $(1)$ translates into:

$$ (x^2+2)\sum_{n\geq 2} n(n-1)a_n x^{n-2} + x\sum_{n\geq 1}na_n x^{n-1} - \sum_{n\geq 0}a_n x^n = 0 \tag{3}$$
that is equivalent to:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 2}n(n-1)a_n x^n +\sum_{n\geq 0}2(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}x^n + \sum_{n\geq 1} n a_n x^n -\sum_{n\geq 0}a_n x^n = 0 \tag{4} $$
Now we consider what is the coefficient of $x^n$ in the last expression and we get that,
 for every $n\geq 2$,
$$ n(n-1) a_n + 2(n+2)(n+1) a_{n+2} + (n-1)a_n = 0\tag{5} $$
hence:
$$ \frac{a_{n+2}}{a_n} = - \frac{(n-1)}{2(n+2)} \tag{6} $$
and by induction:
$$ a_{n+2k} = \frac{(-1)^k}{2^k}\cdot\frac{(n+2k-3)(n+2k-5)\cdot\ldots\cdot(n-1)}{(n+2k)(n+2k-2)\cdot\ldots\cdot(n+2)}\,a_n \tag{7}$$
so a solution of $(1)$ is given by a hypergeometric function.

Comment: but don't you need to equate indices before 5?

Comment: @cjh: the first coefficients depend on the initial conditions. This is a second-order DE, in any case. $(5),(6)$ and $(7)$ hold for any $n\geq 2$ and $k\geq 0$.

Comment: do you know how i can 'leave the answer until 4 non-zero terms?'
the answer is as you (6) but with the "an" on the right side, then goes to form the 4 non-zero terms

Comment: I don't understand your last question.

Comment: i uploaded a picture, can you explain the transition from second line to third line? is there a reason why he can set all indices to 0 without doing anything? what steps have he hidden? thank you very much i need this

Comment: @cjh: it is the principle of analytic continuation: if an analytic function is zero, as given by $(3)$ or $(4)$, all its coefficients have to be zero.

Comment: is there a way you can equate your indices to 0 (4) before proceeding to (5)

Comment: @cjh: it is exacly what I do: I consider the coefficient of $x^n$ in the LHS of $(4)$ and equate it to zero to get $(5)$.

Comment: i mean the number below ∑, make all n=0 ?

Comment: I am having a hard time in understanding what your issues are. The numbers below a $\sum$ sign are the summation indices, so? $\sum_{n\geq 0}$ means $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}$.

Answer (score 0):

Coefficients of $x^n$ on both sides of equation should be equal...